# How to simplify a complex 4k lines if block?

Tags: vba, if-statement, optimization, cascade

I have tried case but isn't enjoy
maybe white "fore cycle or while" 
i use visual basic 2016

I have 10 checkboxes, 3 random numbers from 0 to 9,
 If 3 checkboxes are white, the same 3 numbers as "randomly generated" are checked a textbox become
"the same number as 3 number"

this is an img of checkbox and textbox : [Link](https://prnt.sc/k24fdv) 
This is a huge simplification

```
        If primoR = 0 Then
        If CheckBox10.Checked Then
            If secondoR = 1 Then
                If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                    If terzoR = 2 Then
                        If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                        End If
                    ElseIf terzoR = 3 Then
                        If CheckBox3.Checked Then
                            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                        End If
                    Else
                        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End If
    ElseIf primoR = 1 Then
        If secondoR = 1 Then
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                If terzoR = 2 Then
                    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                    End If
                ElseIf terzoR = 3 Then
                    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
                        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                    End If
                Else
                    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf secondoR = 2 Then

            If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                If terzoR = 2 Then
                    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
                        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                    End If
                ElseIf terzoR = 3 Then
                    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
                        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                    End If
                Else
                    TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
                End If
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf primoR = 2 Then
        'ecc...
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
    End If
    'checkbox10 = 0 , checkbox1 = 1, checkbox1 = 2
```

Here is the [complete code](https://pastebin.com/h4ii6zbD)

Comment: im genuinely concerned about 4 thousand lines of pure if statements.

Comment: please make an [mcve] and put the code here. Code on external site might become invalid when the link dies, and no one will click on that to help you

Comment: Im sure it can be done in 200 lines or less, but don´t know vb

Comment: L_Church me to i realy stoked

Comment: You should be able to make it table driven by using a lookup table - the advantage of that is that is that if you read the table from a file then it becomes part of the configuration and you can change it without recompiling the program.

Comment: I've looked at the "complete code" and it looks like primoR inidcates which checkbox should be checked first and secondoR indicates which checkbox should be checked next and terzoR indicates which checkbox should be checked next.  In that case using something like `CType(Me.Controls("Checkbox"&Iif(primoR=0,10,primoR), CheckboxBox).Checked` could be used to get rid of half the statements then you can table drive the rest of it with only four columns.

Comment: And since you always test every value of primoR, secondoR, and terzoR you can use three nested loops with one If each instead of 10 If statements each time.  I should have an answer ready soon.

Comment: What version of VB are you using?

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer. I couldn't get what you say and what your program is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private randomNumbers As New Random
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim randomNumber1 As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(0, 10)
    Dim randomNumber2 As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(0, 10)
    Dim randomNumber3 As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(0, 10)
    Label1.Text = (randomNumber1 + 1).ToString
    Label2.Text = (randomNumber2 + 1).ToString
    Label3.Text = (randomNumber3 + 1).ToString

    Dim checkA = CType(Me.Controls.Item($"CheckBox{randomNumber1 + 1}"), CheckBox)
    Dim checkB = CType(Me.Controls.Item($"CheckBox{randomNumber2 + 1}"), CheckBox)
    Dim checkC = CType(Me.Controls.Item($"CheckBox{randomNumber3 + 1}"), CheckBox)

    If checkA.Checked AndAlso checkB.Checked And checkC.Checked Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language this is so I don't know if it is VBA (from an Office App), VB6, or VB.Net or something else.   So this may not work out of the box - but it should give you a starting point to work from.

```
  Green = False
  For primoR = 0 To 9
      If CType(Me.Controls("Checkbox" & IIf(primoR = 0, 10, primoR)), CheckboxBox).Checked Then
      For secondoR = 1 To 9
          If CType(Me.Controls("Checkbox" & IIf(secondoR = 0, 10, secondoR)), CheckboxBox).Checked Then
          For terzoR = 0 To 9
              If CType(Me.Controls("Checkbox" & IIf(terzoR = 0, 10, terzoR)), CheckboxBox).Checked Then
                  Green = True
              End If
          Next
      End If
  Next
  TextBox1.BackColor = IIf(Green, Color.Green, Color.Black)
```

Comment: i have 3 number and ok, but in this case it check if i check one random checkbox it become green bat i have 10 of them lock: http://prntscr.com/k24fdv